# multiple forms during configuration of drupal module

Tags: drupal

I have created a Drupal module in which I have multiple stages of configuration. I maintain a variable which stores what state it is in(INITIAL, SECOND etc). Depending on the stage, I want to show a different configuration form to the administrator. I have tried the following code in the **hook_menu**:

```
function mymodule_ldap_menu(){
    $current_status = variable_get('mymodule_status', 'SETUP');
    if($current_status == 'SETUP'){
      $items['admin/config/people/mymodule'] = array(
        'title' => 'Configure Module',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('mymodule_setup_form'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
      );
    } else if ($current_status == 'SECOND'){
          $items['admin/config/people/mymodule'] = array(
          'title' => 'Configure Module: II',
          'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
          'page arguments' => array('mymodule_second_form'),
          'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
          'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
          );
    } else if ($current_status == 'THIRD'){
          $items['admin/config/people/mymodule: III'] = array(
            'title' => 'Configure Module',
            'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'page arguments' => array('mymodule_third_form'),
            'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
            'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        );
      }
    return $items;
  }
```

Initially, I get the form for **SETUP**. I set the value of the **mymodule_status** to **SECOND** when I submit the first form. Even after I click the submit button in the first form, I get shown the first form. I have to clear the cache in order to see the second form. What may be the reason for that? Is it a caching issue? If yes, what do I need to do to prevent the caching?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think `hook_menu` is the right function for this task, because, `hook_menu` is cached, any changes to that function requires you to clear the cache. May be you should look for another hook for your task.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to do is a form wizard, you can see some examples at http://www.sitepoint.com/building-multi-page-wizard-like-form-drupal/ (or with CTools http://internetdevels.com/blog/ctools-multistep-wizard-example).

Anyway, as @xurshid29 said, `hook_menu` is cached, so you need to work on that in your form.